# Installing cpu Cooler inside case/cabinet..safe?

Tags: motherboard, cpu-cooler

Is it safe to put force/pressure to install cooler while the mobo is inside the case/cabinet.Is there a chance of the mobo getting cracked due to force/pressure?

Comment: Wouldn't that kind of depend on the pressure?

Answer (score 1):

General answer:
Never put load / pressure / chemistry / excess heat on a printed circuit board (PCB).

Only acceptable exception: you know it can withstand it as you have the specs, and means to measure / ensure that you DO stay below the limits.

*Notes:*

- A glass fiber laminate PCB flexes quite a bit, the copper strands
  printed on it / inside it (multilayer PCBs) may stretch, bend, crack
  and thereafter cause overheating, short circuits, disturbances and
  other malfunction due to the changed electrical characteristics of
  the leads.
- Surface mounted components and / or solder joints may crack from your
  actions - inevitable malfunction.